# How to install extenion php_intl in centos7?

Tags: centos, php7, remind

I want use `php_intl.dll` in `/etc/opt/remi/php70/ini.php`. So how to install this extension. I use centos7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot install a windows `.dll` on Linux OS

To install `php_intl` on CentOS , you should enable `remi` repo . Open the terminal and run the following commands:

```
wget https://rhel7.iuscommunity.org/ius-release.rpm
sudo rpm -Uvh ius-release*.rpm
```

Update your system then install the `php-intl`:

```
sudo yum update
sudo yum --enablerepo=remi install php-intl
```

To permanently enable `remi` repo , open the terminal and run the following command:

```
sudo nano /etc/yum.repos.d/remi.repo
```

Set `enabled=1`.

Comment: And don't forget to restart apache

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to install php-intl in centos-os (centos ver 2017.09), php version > 7.0.

1. Update system, and try install php-intl directly
2. Install php-intl through IUS and REMI repositories

#### 1. Update system, and try install php-intl directly

UPDATE SYSTEM command

```
sudo yum update
```

INSTALL php70-intl extension

```
sudo yum install -y php70-intl
```

#### 2. Install php-intl through IUS and REMI repositories

INSTALL IUS repository (http://iuscommunity.org/pages/Repos.html#release-packages)

```
cd /opt/
sudo wget https://rhel7.iuscommunity.org/ius-release.rpm
sudo rpm -Uvh ius-release*.rpm
```

If getting epel error like

> epel-release = 7 is needed by ius-release-1.0-15.ius.el7.noarch

you need to install epel-7 through the following command,
and retry the above command.

```
sudo rpm -Uvh https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest- 7.noarch.rpm
```

Update system via

```
sudo yum update
```

Retry ius install

```
sudo rpm -Uvh ius-release*.rpm
```

After IUS is successfully installed, run update system again through command `sudo yum update`.

INSTALL php-intl THROUGH REMI REPOSITORY

Enable remi (temporarily) and install php-intl

```
sudo yum --enablerepo=remi install php-intl
```

IF getting ERROR like

> Error getting repository data for remi, repository not found

you need to install remi repository first, then run the above command.

```
yum install http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm
```

IF getting ERROR like

> php70-common-7.0.32-1.31.amzn1.x86_64 conflicts php-common < 5.5.22-1.98

then you need to install php70-intl directly in place of remi repository.

```
sudo yum install -y php70-intl
```

Comment: No package php70-intl available.